# OrientDB Query Result set of vertices with an empty collection of edges, vertices

Tags: orientdb-2.1

this might be a simple question but I am confused, please help.....

I am using OrientDB 2.1.9 and I am experimenting with VehicleHistoryGraph database.
From Studio, Browse mode, set limit to 9 records only. Now I am entering this simple query

`select out() from Person`

The result set I am getting back is 9 records BUT only two have Bought a vehicle. The rest are displayed with empty collections []. This is no good, I am confused. I would expect to get back only those two vertices with collections of edges !

How do I get back these two persons that bought something ?
I noticed also that there is this unwind operator in select. Is this useful in that case, can you make an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query asks for out(), so out() is computed in all cases, and you're shown the results.  If you only want the rows for which out().size() > 0 then you can construct a query like this:

```
select out() from v let n=out().size() where $n > 0
```

If you think that one ought to be able to write this more succintly, e.g. like so:

```
select out() as n from v where n > 0
```

then join the club (e.g. by supporting [this enhancement request](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5623)).

(`select out() from v where out().size() > 0` is supported.)

Comment: @Athanassios - Thanks, I've updated the text accordingly. But did you mean to write "AtomicDB"?